# Riemann zeta-function functional equation form

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

In Titchmarch's book the functional equation is given as
$$\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin \left( \frac{s\pi}2\right) \Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s).$$
However, in the third proof, he derives a following equation
$$\pi^{-\frac{s}2}\Gamma\left( \frac{s}2\right) \zeta(s)=\pi^{-\frac12+\frac{s}2}\Gamma\left( \frac12-\frac{s}2\right) \zeta(1-s)$$
and simply states that our initial equation follows from our derived equation. Can somebody explain to me how exactly?

Comment: Hint: This boils down to a Gamma function relation. Apply the  Gamma function duplication formula http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5 for $z=(1-s)/2$. This gives you two terms $\Gamma(1/2-s/2)$ and $\Gamma(1-s/2),\;$ for the last use the reflection formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We obviously have
$$ \zeta(s) = \pi^{- \frac{1}{2} + s} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})} \zeta(1 - s).$$
We now use the duplication formula in the form $\Gamma(z + \frac{1}{2}) = 2^{1 - 2z} \sqrt{\pi} \frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(z)}$, where $z = -\frac{s}{2}$. This yields
$$\pi^{- \frac{1}{2} + s} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})} = 2^{1 + s} \pi^s \frac{\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(-\frac{s}{2})\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})}.$$
Now using Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z) \Gamma(1 - z)}$ for $z = -\frac{s}{2}$ gives us
\begin{align*}2^{1 + s} \pi^s \frac{\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(-\frac{s}{2})\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})} 
&= 2^{1 + s} \pi^{s-1} \frac{\Gamma(-s)\Gamma(1 + \frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})} \sin(-\frac{\pi s}{2}) \\
&= 2^{1 + s} \pi^{s-1} \frac{\frac{s}{2} \Gamma(-s)\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})} \sin(-\frac{\pi s}{2})\\
&= -2^{s} \pi^{s-1} \Gamma(1-s)\sin(-\frac{\pi s}{2}) \\
&= 2^{s} \pi^{s-1} \Gamma(1-s)\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}).\end{align*}

Comment: Please, how you obtain the second identity after that you use **Euler's reflection formula**?

Comment: $\Gamma(z + 1) = z\Gamma(z)$, or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, now I understand!